# in a MAUI application, for application settings, is it better appsetings.json or Preferences.Default?

Tags: maui

I would like to have some default setting in my application, so for this settings I was thinking to add a appsettings.json file a embedded file.

But there are another settings that can be set by the user, so in this case, I don't if it is a good idea to use a json file, because I don't know if I can update parameters in the file.

Also I have seen that MAUI has the option to save in preferences and in SecureStorage, so I was thinking that it could be a good option. In this case, perhaps I could copy the default settings from my json file to preferences in MauiProgram.cs and work always with preferences.

So I would like to know when it is better or in which cases json it is better option than preferences or if they have different purposes and are different things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I prefer to keep an AppSettings.json file that I can use for development, and I have another one that I use for the production/staging environment.

During the building in the pipeline, I replace the original appsettings.json with another one depending on the environment in that I will deploy the app.

In [Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops), you have the option of secure files, that allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded file is read-only in the project at the runtime. So when you realse/deploy the project, you can't write appsettings.json any more.

But you said:

> But there are another settings that can be set by the user

So you need to both read and write this file. **The Preferences.Default is a better choice**, because it store in the device internal storage. You can read and write it easily. In addition, you can also open it directly in the system file manager.

Comment: I would do both. An `AppSettings.json` file for the same reasons as @marcos-costa and use `Preferences.Default` for things that can be updated (and load defaults from the appsetting on first startu ). `Preferences.Default` is pretty limitted on its own (no arrays, no complex types) so you can also use the local storage and handle your own setting file in `FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory`.